# Attach "admin/" prefix into url in Yii.urlManager

Tags: php, yii

I have a problem with Yii url's.

I want to add 'admin/' prefix to every url created by gii (CRUD for my model).

when I create basic CRUD for "Offer", the url to {add|edit|del} views starts from 'offer/...', but i want to add 'admin/' before 'offer/'.

- offer/1 -> admin/offer/1
- offer/index -> admin/offer/index
- offer/update/1 -> admin/offer/update/1
- 
- 

Maybe someone can point me to the right answer or give me some advice.

Thank you :)

Comment: The best approach accomplished this issua is create module. (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module#using-module).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution based on your examples. Add the following to your 'rules' array of 'urlManager' :

```
'admin/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view', //offer/1 -> admin/offer/1
'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>', //offer/index -> admin/offer/index,
'admin/<controller:\w*>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=> '<controller>/<action>', //offer/update/1 -> admin/offer/update/1
```

You can notice the pattern right, there. More info about url manager can be found here : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpfull for me. But, I just find way to do such thing. While creating in gii basic CRUD, we can set "Controller ID" as "admin/your_controller". And after that our controller is available under "admin/your_controller/{index|update|delete|...}"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom url rule for use in the urlManager. It re-writes the route (provided you are using CHtml::link or similar) to the format you want. When the link is clicked by the user the url path is translated back to the correct route and given to the right controller.

There is more information here and an example.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes